# How many unique Pokémon formes are there?

Tags: pokemon-series

Some Pokémon only have one version and one shiny version, so 2 total formes/sprites/call them whatever you like. Some others, however, have several. Examples include Vivillon (20 known patterns), Meowstic (prominent gender differences) and Deoxys (different activatable formes).

I'm looking for the total number **excluding Mega Evolutions, Spiky-Eared Pichu and Spinda**, specifically:

- How many unique formes are there **at all**?
- How many unique formes can one have **at the same time**, assuming enough Pokémon are accessible? (As far as I know, you can't have both Black and White Kyurem at the same time, for example)
- How many of these are available **in storage**, that is, don't get lost when the Pokémon is put into a PC box?

It would be great to have the answer updated as new Pokémon and formes are released, but in any case, I'd like to have an answer as of X/Y.

The versions count as different if they are visually different. Things such as evolution that differs depending on gender don't count as different formes.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without some firm way of determining when gender dfferences become "prominent" (does Hippopotas count? Frillish? Unfezant? Combee?).

Comment: Let's just say no gender differences except ones that could be a different Pokémon (like meowstick) or have obviously different color.

Comment: Eevee and its seven different forms?

Comment: @scenia: Still not good enough. When "could it be a different Pokémon"? Are the two Pyroar genders sufficiently dissimilar? What about Snover? What about differences in evolution (Combee, Kirlia)? Without a complete and objective criteria, you can't give an authoritative answer.

Comment: It's only about visual differences in the same species. The seven "forms" of eevee are evolutions and thus different species. They count as two each. @Michael i see your point and changed my mind. Take into account all visual gender differences. I don't know if you can switch gender on the pokedex if there's no difference, but if you can't, then pokedex entries are the criterion.

Comment: So, Gligar would count as having 4 forms because the stinger of the male is slightly larger than that of the female one (double because of shiny)? And Pikachu would have 4 as well (heart-shaped tail + shiny of each)?

Comment: @Jerry yes. While we're at it, why not make it complete?

Comment: @Michael, for reference, I found a list and would consider only 7 species "prominent": Hippopotas, Hippowdon, Unfezant, Frillish, Jellicent, Pyroar and Meowstick.

Comment: Unown forms? Also, shiny ones?

Comment: Yes, all of 'em!

Comment: Preliminary research yields a number of 1781 storable/transferable Sprites. This is not counting item-based formes such as Arceus or Giratina, counts Rotom as 2 because it reverts to its normal Forme when traded and respects species unobtainable as Shiny versions (e.g. Arceus, Reshiram, ...). 182 of those are normal and Shiny sprites of Pokémon with "minor" gender differences such as longer hair, different coloration on small parts of the body or similar differences that are hard to spot without seeing both sprites.

Comment: I get 1780 and have a list [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HhZT0XQ67TeBID75c2yVs7F4kDAN-xEkGwEvAXC22a8/edit?usp=sharing). Unless I'm counting not something you deem as a true form/sprite/whatever, it should be complete. Numbers left aligned are not counted and is just for reference. The female column includes 'minor' differences.

Comment: You didn't count shiny mew. It's only unavailable in Gen 2. The Japanese emerald had an event where you could catch mew in the wild on some event-only Island, so it does legitimately exist as a shiny.

Comment: @scenia Well, yes, in that case.

Comment: @Jerry i just looked through your list and interestingly, it differs quite a bit from mine. Basically, you counted a few formes i didn't, and didn't count several legendary shinies (as far as i know, only Jirachi fails the legality check, so all other shinies obtained legitimately in earlier versions should pass.

Comment: @scenia I didn't count Japanese releases, but if I count them, that makes only two more, being Mew and Celebi. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jerry Before Black/White, any Legendary encountered in the wild could be shiny, so they all have shiny versions. You counted nearly none of them. I'm not sure which ones you counted but I didn't, though. I'm compiling a list and will post an answer.

Comment: I got it, you counted Meloetta (always in Aria Forme outside of battle), Spiky-Eared Pichu (only available in Gen IV) and Furfrou (always in Natural Form while stored).

Comment: Okay, that makes still 1775 if you exclude them and add some shiny legendaries. Arceus for example could never be shiny though. What's even the objective of the question if I may ask?

Comment: I want to know how many unique Pokémon (ignoring stats, of course) I can have on Pokémon bank, creating a 100% complete living Pokédex. I'm also interested in how many sprites I will have to "activate" after transferring everything onto a fresh game.

Comment: Well... [Spinda](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Spinda_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Trivia) has a different spot pattern for each possible personality value, so there are ~4.3billion unique Spinda sprites.

Comment: @JRandomHacker Good point. I fixed the question.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie "forme(s)" is the official term used in the game as well as promotional material, however wrong the word may be.

Comment: @scenia Ah, my bad!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Sun & Moon, the post below is no longer accurate. I will leave it below unedited for reference purposes.

New in Sun & Moon:

- **81 new Pokemon** with their own National Pokedex number
- **18 new regional variants** (Alolan Forms) of Gen I Pokemon (*Rattata, Raticate, Raichu, Sandshrew, Sandslash, Vulpix, Ninetales, Diglett, Dugtrio, Meowth, Persian, Geodude, Graveler, Golem, Grimer, Muk, Exeggutor, Marowak*)
- **11 new additional storable Formes** (*1 Zygarde, 3 Oricorio, 1 Lycanroc, 6 Minior*)
- **17 new additional Item-induced Formes** (*Silvally*)
- **6 new Battle-activated Formes** (*1 Zygarde, 1 Wishiwashi, 1 Minior, 1 Mimikyu, 1 Solgaleo, 1 Lunala*)
- All of these in a **shiny version**, of which **18 are unobtainable** (*4 Tapus, Cosmog, Cosmoem, Solgaleo, Lunala, 7 Ultra Beasts, Necrozma, Magearna, Marshadow*)

This puts the new totals at **1990 unique storable sprites** (1789+(81+18+10)*2-18 +1 Zygarde), 2018 including unobtainable ones and **2133 total sprites** (1889+(81+18+10)*2-18+(17+5)*2 -1 Solgaleo -1 Lunala +2 Zygarde).

---

After quite some research time and thanks to Jerry's help, I was able to compile a complete list. Here are the numbers involved. As per the question, Mega Evolutions are excluded. Also excluded is Spiky-Eared Pichu, which only existed in Gen IV and cannot be transferred to newer generations, as well as Spinda, which has an absurd amount of technically different sprites (one per 32-bit PID).

- There are currently **721 Pokémon** on the National Pokédex, including Diancie, Hoopa and Volcanion.
- Of these, **91 females** have minor gender differences and **7 females** have major differences (*Hippopotas, Hippowdon, Unfezant, Frillish, Jellicent, Pyroar* and *Meowstick*).
- The number of additional storable **(permanent) alternate formes** is **81** (*27 Unown, 3 Deoxys, 2 Burmy, 2 Wormadam, 1 Shellos, 1 Gastrodon, 1 Basculin, 3 Deerling, 3 Sawsbuck, 1 Keldeo, 19 Vivillon, 4 Flabébé, 4 Floette, 4 Florges, 3 Pumpkaboo, 3 Gourgeist*).
- There are **34 additional Item-activated alternate formes** (*5 Rotom, 1 Giratina, 1 Shaymin, 17 Arceus, 1 Tornadus, 1 Thundurus, 1 Landorus, 2 Kyurem, 4 Genesect, 1 Hoopa*).
- You can transform Pokémon into **7 additional Battle-based formes** (*3 Castform, 1 Cherrim, 1 Darmanitan, 1 Meloetta, 1 Aegislash*).
- Then there are **10 additional special formes** (*9 Furfrou, 1 Xerneas*).
- And lastly, all of these exist in a **shiny version**, except for **8 non-obtainable shinies** and **3 alternate formes** (*Celebi, Victini, Keldeo, Resolute Keldeo, Meloetta, Poké Ball Vivillon, Fancy Vivillon, Zygarde, Diancie, Hoopa, Volcanion*).

This means that the total number of **storable unique sprites is 1789** ( (721+91+7+81)*2 -8 -1 Keldeo -2 Vivillon, interestingly exactly 1800 including currently unobtainable ones).

The **total number of sprites** including battle-induced, item-induced and special forms is **1889** (1789 + (34+7+10)*2 -1 Meloetta -1 Hoopa).

Comment: You forgot all the different patterns for Spinda if you really want to count minor differences

Comment: @Styxsksu Spinda is one of the things explicitly excluded in the question (along with Mega Evolutions and Spiky-Eared Pichu).

Answer (score 1):

Bulbapedia has a [list of Pokémon forms](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Form_differences). As of this time, it contains:

- Pichu, which can be Spiky-Eared Pichu
- Unown, which have a total of 28 different forms (the 26 letters of the alphabet plus ? and !)
- Castform, which due to its ability Forecast, can turn into Sunny, Rainy, and Snowy forms based on the weather
- Deoxys, which can be in Normal, Attack, Defense, or Speed forms based on game (in Gen III) or based on what meteorite you just inspected (Gens IV, V, VI)
- Burmy and female Wormadam, which can have Plant, Sandy, or Trash cloaks based on what terrain it last battled in (as a Burmy)
- Cherrim, which due to its ability Flower Gift, flips between Overcast and Sunshine forms based on whether the weather is sunny
- Shellos and Gastorodon, which have different appearances depending on whether they come from the West coast or the East coast
- Rotom, which can possess appliances to convert to Heat, Wash, Frost, Fan, or Mow forms
- Giratina, which is in its Origin form inside the Distortion World (or it holds the Griseous Orb) and its Altered form otherwise
- Shaymin, which turns into its Sky form upon contact with the Gracidea item and reverts to its Land form at night or if frozen
- Basculin, which can be Red-Striped or Blue-Striped depending whether the game is Black(2) or White(2) (though rare instances of the other can occur)
- Darmanitan, which flips between Standard and Zen mode based on whether its HP is above or below half
- Deerling and Sawsbuck, which match the season of Spring, Summer, Autumn, and Winter (anything other than Spring has to be transferred in Gen VI, as seasons do not exist there)
- Tornadus, Thundurus, and Landorus, which depending on how they are obtained can be in their Incarnate or Therian form
- Kyruem, which can be fused/unfused to Reshiram or Zekrom with DNA Splicers to form White or Black forms
- Keldeo, which converts between Ordinary and Resolute forms depending on whether it knows Secret Sword
- Meloetta, which temporarily changes from Aria to Pirouette form if it uses Relic Song
- Vivillion, which has 18 different player-location-based forms (Archipelago, Continental, Elegant, Garden, High Plains, Icy Snow, Jungle, Marine, Meadow, Modern, Monsoon, Ocean, Polar, River, Sandstorm, Savanna, Sun, Tundra) and 2 event forms (Poké Ball, Fancy)
- Flabébé, Floette, and Florges, which match the colour of the flower bed they're caught in (Red, Yellow, Orange, Blue, White)
- Furfrou, which can be groomed from Normal to Heart, Star, Diamond, Debutante, Matron, Dandy, La Reine, Kabuki, or Pharaoh trims for 5 days
- Aegislash, which converts between Blade and Shield forms when it uses offensive moves/King's Shield
- Pumpkaboo and Gourgeist, which come in Small, Average, Large, and Super sizes
- Xerneas, which is in Neutral mode for cutscenes and Active mdoe for battle

Comment: I refined the question, I forgot to mention i was also interested specifically in those available in storage. Also, which ones are available in a shiny version/keep their differences? Could you add the total number deduced from your list?

Comment: @Toomai - The different forms of Basculin can also be caught in the X/Y games in different streams or when using different rods.

Comment: Can you have both black and white kyurem? Are they transferable in their fused formes?